# Do the messages with the same key but from different Kafka producers go to different partitions?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have two Kafka producers send messages to the same topic that has multiple partitions.

The messages with the same key K1 from the same producer PR1 always go to the same partition PA1, as expected.

The problem is the messages with the same key K1 from the other producer PR2 go to another partition PA2 while I expect they also go to PA1.

Doesn't Kafka keep the partition assignment across producers?

Is it related to the two producers use different Kafka client libraries?

Will it help if I set the two producers to use the same id?

Comment: If you sent message with key1 and after it message with the same key1, from one or more than one producer, it should end in the same partition. Do you maybe increased number of partitions between sending those 2 messages?

Comment: Which client libraries are you using? And what version of Apache Kafka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your comments and answers.

The cause is one of the Kafka libraries `node-rdkafka` uses a different default partitioner from the Java producer, https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/issues/616.

Changing the `partioner` configuration to `murmur2_random` works.

Answer (score 0):

How messages are assigned to partitions can be configured per-producer based on the [configuration set](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs) with `partitioner.class` passed to the Producer API. There is an [interface](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Partitioner.html) if you want to write your own.

This defaults to `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner`, which uses a hash of the key to ensure that all messages for the same key end up in the same partition.